# Create objects within a foreach to push to an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, api, xserver

What I am trying to achieve is to split a string into multiple adresses like "NL,VENLO,5928PN" which getLocation will return a "POINT( x y)" string value.

This works. Next I need to create a WayPointDesc object for each location. And each of these objects has to be pushed into the WayPointDesc[]. I have tried various methods but I cannot find a feasable option so far. My last resort is to hardcode a maximum amount of waypoints but I would rather avoid such a thing.

Using a list is unfortunately not an option... I think.

This is the function:

```
    /* tour()
     * Input: string route
     * Output: string[] [0] DISTANCE [1] TIME [2] MAP
     * Edited 21/12/12 - Davide Nguyen
     */
    public string[] tour(string route)
    {
        // EXAMPLE INPUT FROM QUERY
        route = "NL,HELMOND,5709EM+NL,BREDA,8249EN+NL,VENLO,5928PN"; 
        string[] waypoints = route.Split('+');

        // Do something completly incomprehensible
        foreach (string point in waypoints)
        {
            xRoute.WaypointDesc wpdStart = new xRoute.WaypointDesc();
            wpdStart.wrappedCoords = new xRoute.Point[] { new xRoute.Point() };
            wpdStart.wrappedCoords[0].wkt = getLocation(point);
        }

        // Put the strange result in here somehow
        xRoute.WaypointDesc[] waypointDesc = new xRoute.WaypointDesc[] { wpdStart };

        // Calculate the route information
        xRoute.Route route = calculateRoute(waypointDesc);
        // Generate the map, travel distance and travel time using the route information
        string[] result = createMap(route);
        // Return the result
        return result;

        //WEEKEND?
    }
```

Comment: Why can't you use a List and then call ToArray on it when done?

Comment: isn't wpdStart out of scope the way you have this currently implemented?

Comment: @mletterle Thanks. I have just done that.

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc It is a prototype function that hasn't been called yet. Code has been cleaned up and now that this works amazing, I can begin cleaning up my class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays are fixed-length, if you want to dynamically add elements, you need to use some type of linked list structure.  Also, your wpdStart variable was out of scope when you were adding it originally.

```
    List<xRoute.WaypointDesc> waypointDesc = new List<xRoute.WaypointDesc>();

    // Do something completly incomprehensible
    foreach (string point in waypoints)
    {
        xRoute.WaypointDesc wpdStart = new xRoute.WaypointDesc();
        wpdStart.wrappedCoords = new xRoute.Point[] { new xRoute.Point() };
        wpdStart.wrappedCoords[0].wkt = getLocation(point);

        // Put the strange result in here somehow
        waypointDesc.add(wpdStart);
    }
```

If you really want the list as an array later, use: `waypointDesc.ToArray()`

Comment: ermergurd. That works perfectly. All I needed to add was. I'll be using this more often.

        xRoute.WaypointDesc[] finalWaypointDesc = waypointDesc.ToArray();

Comment: FYI `List<T>` isn't a linked list.  It is actually a dynamic array under the hood.